# Tricks to get reverse-order cumulative histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, cumulative-frequency

I am wondering if there is a (better) trick to reverse a cumulative histogram in matplotlib.

Let's say I have some scores in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 where 1.0 is the best score. Now, I am interested to plot how many samples are **above** a certain score threshold.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.random.normal(size=1000)
d = (d - d.min()) / (d.max() - d.min())

plt.hist(d, 50, histtype="stepfilled", alpha=.7)
```

[image]

By default, matplotlib would plot the cumulative histogram like with 'number of samples <= score'

```
plt.hist(d, 50, histtype="stepfilled", alpha=.7, cumulative=True)
```

[image]

What I acutally want is the cumulative histogram not show  'number of samples <= score' but  'number of samples >= score'

I could do it like this, but then how would I get rid of the "minus" sign on the x-axis?

```
plt.hist(d-1, 50, histtype="stepfilled", alpha=.7, cumulative=True)
```

[image]

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pretty sure you can just use `cumulative=-1` in your function call:

```
plt.hist(d, 50, histtype="stepfilled", alpha=.7, cumulative=-1)
```

From the matplotlib hist() docs:

> If cumulative evaluates to less than 0 (e.g., -1), the direction of accumulation is reversed.

Take a look at the third example image [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html); I think it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.